# Highcharts gauge do not display

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gauge

I have a problem with the Highcharts gauge.
Actually, it doesn't display and I have a JS error.

`TypeError: $[b.defaultSeriesType] is not a constructor` highcharts.js (line 159)

I have 3 tabs (using bootstrap/jquery) with pie in the two others and there is no problem with these ones.

I don't understand because I have just copied the example from the Highcharts website. Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

**EDIT :**

Here is a part of the JS

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

                                chart : {
                                    renderTo : 'container',
                                    type : 'gauge',
                                    plotBackgroundColor : null,
                                    plotBackgroundImage : null,
                                    plotBorderWidth : 0,
                                    plotShadow : false
                                },

                                title : {
                                    text : 'Speedometer'
                                },

                                pane : {
                                    startAngle : -150,
                                    endAngle : 150,
                                    background : [
                                            {
                                                backgroundColor : {
                                                    linearGradient : {
                                                        x1 : 0,
                                                        y1 : 0,
                                                        x2 : 0,
                                                        y2 : 1
                                                    },
                                                    stops : [
                                                            [ 0, '#FFF' ],
                                                            [ 1, '#333' ] ]
                                                },
                                                borderWidth : 0,
                                                outerRadius : '109%'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                backgroundColor : {
                                                    linearGradient : {
                                                        x1 : 0,
                                                        y1 : 0,
                                                        x2 : 0,
                                                        y2 : 1
                                                    },
                                                    stops : [
                                                            [ 0, '#333' ],
                                                            [ 1, '#FFF' ] ]
                                                },
                                                borderWidth : 1,
                                                outerRadius : '107%'
                                            }, {
                                            // default background
                                            }, {
                                                backgroundColor : '#DDD',
                                                borderWidth : 0,
                                                outerRadius : '105%',
                                                innerRadius : '103%'
                                            } ]
                                },

                                // the value axis
                                yAxis : {
                                    min : 0,
                                    max : 200,

                                    minorTickInterval : 'auto',
                                    minorTickWidth : 1,
                                    minorTickLength : 10,
                                    minorTickPosition : 'inside',
                                    minorTickColor : '#666',

                                    tickPixelInterval : 30,
                                    tickWidth : 2,
                                    tickPosition : 'inside',
                                    tickLength : 10,
                                    tickColor : '#666',
                                    labels : {
                                        step : 2,
                                        rotation : 'auto'
                                    },
                                    title : {
                                        text : 'km/h'
                                    },
                                    plotBands : [ {
                                        from : 0,
                                        to : 120,
                                        color : '#55BF3B' // green
                                    }, {
                                        from : 120,
                                        to : 160,
                                        color : '#DDDF0D' // yellow
                                    }, {
                                        from : 160,
                                        to : 200,
                                        color : '#DF5353' // red
                                    } ]
                                },

                                series : [ {
                                    name : 'Speed',
                                    data : [ 80 ],
                                    tooltip : {
                                        valueSuffix : ' km/h'
                                    }
                                } ]
                            });
```

And in my html I have this

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="requetesSeconde">

            <div id="container"
                style="width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


        </div>
```

Comment: Can you put this up for us to see? I'd guess you are using the new keyword where you shouldn't.

Comment: I suggest removing parts until you identify the error :-) Looks to me, on brief inspection, to be the series. See http://jsfiddle.net/fWvCT/
If you could put your code up on JSFiddle in its' entirety, that'd be a help for the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that you have not included `highcharts-more.js` file

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange because I copied the example.
Maybe there is a problem because of the number of charts on the page. (3 in the first tab, 1 in the second one and the gauge in the third one)